# JQuery looking for the nearest or the value of a label input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, find, label

I am new to JQuery. I want to find my inputted value in many labels. I have a Find button. Here is my html. [Here is my screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ll2.png)

And here is my JQuery code, i tried different codes, but none of them seems to find what I am looking for, below my code has an error.

```
$(".button1").on("click", function() {
        var el = document.getElementById("labelValue")
        text = (el.innerText || el.textContent);
        alert(text);
    });
```

and here is my Code 2 which is not working also.

```
$(".button1").on("click", function() {
        var q = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().find('label.labelValue').html(q);
        console.log(q);
        alert(JSON.stringify(q));
    });
```

and here is my html code.

```
<div class="row g-0" id="chartTen" style="display:none;">
    <h4 class="card-title">TANK REPLIMISHMENT RATE</h4>
    <label>TEST METHOD </label> <select onchange="reveal_test(this)">
        <!--<select id="reveal_label" name="reveal_label">-->
        <option disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">SELECT AN OPTION</option>
        <option value="testM1" style="font-weight: bold">HYDRANT FLOW TESTER</option>
        <option value="testM2" style="font-weight: bold">PROBE</option>
        <option value="testM3" style="font-weight: bold">ULTRASONIC</option>
    </select><br>

    <h4 class="card-title" style="display:none;" id="probe">ULTRASONIC TESTER</h4>
    <label style="display:none;" id="probeLabel"><input type="text" /> FLOW RATE L/S </label>

    <h4 class="card-title" id="ultra" style="display:none;">PROBE TESTER</h4>
    <table id="dataTable2" style="display:none;">
        <caption><button data-op="add" title="add new row"> &#10010; </button> </caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label></label>
                    <input type="text6" value="0" class="randomColor" />
                    <label> L/MIN @ </label>
                    <button data-op="del" title="delete row"> &#10006; </button>
                    <button class="button1">FIND</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
<table id="annubarHead" style="display:none;">
    <!--<table>-->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 750px; background-color: gray;">ANNUBAR FLOW TEST RESULTS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table id="annubarHeadTable" style="display:none;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: gray; text-align: center;">
                INCHES OF MERCURY
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: gray; text-align: center; width: 100% !important;">
                MODEL 20T, SINGLE MOUNT 3/8" Dia Probe Size<br>
                <select onchange="reveal_label(this)">
                    <!--<select id="reveal_label" name="reveal_label">-->
                    <option disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">SELECT AN OPTION</option>
                    <option value="dn1" style="font-weight: bold">20T DN50</option>
                    <option value="dn2" style="font-weight: bold">20T DN65</option>
                    <option value="dn3" style="font-weight: bold">20T DN80</option>
                    <option value="dn4" style="font-weight: bold">20T DN90</option>
                    <option value="dn5" style="font-weight: bold">20T DN100</option>
                    <option value="dn6" style="font-weight: bold">20T DN125</option>
                    <option value="dn7" style="font-weight: bold">20T DN150</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    0
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="labelValues" id="dnValue0" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                <label for="labelValues" id="dnValue1" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                <label for="labelValues" id="dnValue2" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                <label for="labelValues" id="dnValue3" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                <label for="labelValues" id="dnValue4" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                <label for="labelValues" id="dnValue5" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                <label for="labelValues" id="dnValue6" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Whenever i click the button, i want to find the nearest value or the same value and will have a prompt where it is located.
Your help will be a great benefit for me. Thank you so much. Please look at the comments.

Comment: Hi, I would like have more clear understanding regarding your requirement. So based on your screenshot for example: when user input "840" it will give result **14** because 826.05 is the nearest value, and if user input "841" it will give result **15** because 855.04 is nearest value. Am I correct?

Comment: Hello @SternChen, You are right, and If I Inputted the same value as 826.05 it will only mark number 14 which is 826.05, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can have a function to extract the data from your current table:

```
/* get data from current table */
function getData() {
    /* loop through table row */
    const data = $('#the-table').find('tbody > tr').toArray().map(row => {
        /* get inches and value from cells in each row by class name */
        const inches = $(row).find('.label-inch').first().html()
        const value = $(row).find('.label-value').first().html()

        /* return as object e.g. { inches: 1, value: 12.34 } */
        return { inches, value }
    })

    return data
}
```

Function above should return an array of object like this:

```
[
    {
        "inches": "0",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "inches": "1",
        "value": "220.77"
    },
    /* ...more */
]
```

Next you need a function to find the closest value from the data you have extracted from function above by a given value:

```
/* find closest value */
function findClosest(needle) {
    /* get current table data */
    const data = getData()

    /* find closest value by compare the value difference  */
    const closest = data.reduce((a, b) => {
        /* comparing "value" attribute */
        return Math.abs(b.value - needle) < Math.abs(a.value - needle) ? b : a
    })

    return closest
}
```

Finally bind a click event on the *Find* button to read user input and get the closest value result:

```
/* bind click event on "Find" button */
$('#find').click(function() {
    /* get user input */
    const input = $('#value-to-find').val()

    /* find the closest value based on user input */
    const closest = findClosest(input)

    /* render the result */
    const html = `Inches: ${closest.inches}, value: ${closest.value}`
    $('#result').html(html)
})
```

**Demo**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* *This is not part of the function* */
  generateTheChart()

  /* bind click event on "Find" button */
  $('#find').click(function() {
    /* get user input */
    const input = $('#value-to-find').val()

    /* find the closest value based on user input */
    const closest = findClosest(input)

    /* render the result */
    const html = `Inches: ${closest.inches}, value: ${closest.value}`
    $('#result').html(html)
  })
})

/* get data from current table */
function getData() {
  /* loop through table row */
  const data = $('#the-table').find('tbody > tr').toArray().map(row => {
    /* get inches and value from cells in each row by class name */
    const inches = $(row).find('.label-inch').first().html()
    const value = $(row).find('.label-value').first().html()

    /* return as object e.g. { inches: 1, value: 12.34 } */
    return {
      inches,
      value
    }
  })

  return data
}

/* find closest value */
function findClosest(needle) {
  /* get current table data */
  const data = getData()

  /* find closest value by compare the value difference  */
  const closest = data.reduce((a, b) => {
    /* comparing "value" attribute */
    return Math.abs(b.value - needle) < Math.abs(a.value - needle) ? b : a
  })

  return closest
}

/* *This is not part of the function* */
function generateTheChart() {
  const values = ['0.00', '220.77', '312.22', '382.39', '441.54', '493.66', '540.78', '584.11', '624.43', '662.31', '698.14', '732.21', '764.77', '796.00', '826.05', '855.04', '883.08']
  const html = values.reduce((str, value, index) => `${str}<tr><td class="label-inch">${index}</td><td class="label-value">${value}</td></tr>`, '')
  $('#the-table').find('tbody').append(html)
}
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<label for="value-to-find">
        Find
    </label>
<input id="value-to-find" type="text" name="find">
<button id="find" type="button">Find</button>
<p>Result: <span id="result"></span></p>
<hr />
<table id="the-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Inches of mercury</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**New example added of how to select the value based on your html provided**:

```
/* get first column from row, and get value from label */
const inches = $(row).find('td').first().find('label').html()

/* get second column from row, and get value from label where is invisible */
const value = $(row).find('td').eq(1).find('label:visible').html()
```

Comment: Hello @Stern Chen, is it okay if the table I am looking for is on different one, but they have the same <div> and also the value would be different because there will be a drop down there. when I click the dropdown, another set of value will pop up and remove the existing value, that is why I am using display:none

Comment: i have a problem with this, how can I find my label textcontents given with my sample in <tr>, this is the issue const inches = $(row).find('.label-inch').first().html()
        const value = $(row).find('.label-value').first().html()

Comment: Hello @Stern Chen, this is the error i am getting Uncaught TypeError: data3334.reduce is not a function at findClosest

Comment: **1.** Yes, it will be fine even if you have different set of tables, because the function will always get the current table data.
**2.** You may replace `$(row).find('.label-inch').first().html()` with the one I just added, which I have edited my answer to add a code example based on your html provided.
**3.** You can try **2.**, and see whether ` data3334.reduce is not a function` error still exists.

Comment: Hello @Stern Chen, I am getting this error. Uncaught TypeError: data.reduce is not a function
    at findClosest, I didn't include this one " generateTheChart() " and I did not create an array because I have already datas on my chart.

Comment: Yes the `generateTheChart()` is not required. Can you try `console.log(data)` at a line before the `data.reduce`? And check the what `data` contains and show me.

Comment: Hello this is inside the console,S.fn.init [prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]
length: 0
prevObject: S.fn.init [table#annubarHeadTable]
[[Prototype]]: Object(0). Thank you.

Comment: From this probably your `getData()` didn't return an array of data objects. You can see the example in my answer which stated "**Function above should return an array of object like this:**", the `getData()` must return an array which like the example I given.

Comment: Hello @Stern Chen, do i need to have multiple arrays? because i have multiple arrays per drop down at my chart.

Comment: No, you don't need multiple arrays. As I mentioned above, the `getData()` should only get the current table data only, regardless of how many drop down table selection you have.

Comment: Hello @Stern Chen, please check my code here at fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/dvrf7hn4/1/

Comment: I have fixed the code for you: https://jsfiddle.net/14z3xcL9/. You check it and try understand the code.

Comment: Hello Stern, it is working thank you, what if I want to have it also on my add button trigger. so when i click the add button it will also duplicate the function but will print other set of results. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, I not really understand your question. What other set of results you want to print?

Comment: Hello, I have it here. it shows undefined when i add the input. Here is the link of my question, it has the fiddle too. I cannot append the input or I cannot find it and it don't show the span which is hidden. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603699/trouble-in-looping

Comment: Hello @Stern Chen, I am playing with your code at jsfiddle. When I am duplicating the codes, it has an input error, I am trying to figure out or adding multiple input fields. I just changed the input ids, and other constructors.

Comment: It has a result of 0 inches and 0 values